# Setting up Contact Form in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm relatively new to Xcode, and am trying to style and create a very basic app before I move onto more complex things - so I'm learning all the time.

So I've got my Contact Form view controller all styled up, and I'd like to figure out how to pull the inputted data through so when the user clicks Submit, it send it all through to the defined email address. I'm aware this requires a bit of php server side which I'm happy with, but it's the basic collating in Xcode that's causing an issue - allocating actions/code etc.

Plenty of tutorials explain how to create a form from scratch, but it's implementing it into an existing project that's proving tricky - I have a view Controller setup already with the required interface.

The screenshot of my view controller is here: http://pixelproofdesign.co.uk/stackoverflow/View%20Controller%20Screenshot.png

You can find the project files here: http://pixelproofdesign.co.uk/stackoverflow/Pixel%20Proof_NEW.zip

Any help would be hugely appreciated - it's driving me round the bend!

Answer (score 1):

Connect each text field of the form to an outlet in the .H file. This will then allow you to get at the text property when the user taps the Contact Us button.

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *contactName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *contactEmail;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *contactPhone;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *contactDescription;

Add an action to that button and concatenate the text fields into an NSString, e.g.

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&phone=%@&description=%@",
                     self.contactName.text,
                     self.contactEmail.text,
                     self.contactPhone.text,
                     self.contactDescription.text];
```

Then you can send this as a POST and the PHP will get each field as a variable. See also [sending form data via HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486877/sending-form-data-via-http-post-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks! I've got each field called to the relevant outlet in the .h file - but where do I place the NSString code? I assume this will be linked to the 'Contact Us' button. I've added the current screenshot of the viewcontroller and .h file here: http://pixelproofdesign.co.uk/stackoverflow/updated%20h%20file.png

Comment: yes, connect the Contact Us button to a method in the .M file and place the NSString definition there. You'll then convert that string to an NSData object for passing to the NSMutableRequest

Answer (score 0):

when you are done collecting data build up up a NSDictionary

```
id dict = @{@"formField1": formField1.stringValue; @"FormField2": formField2.stringValue};
```

=> the resulting dictionary you form encode so you can put it to html ([category to get postData](https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDUtils/tree/master/model/NSDictionary+PostData%20%5Bios%20+%20osx%5D)

```
id data = [dict postData];
```

=> then transfer it using NSURLConnection

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.url.de"]];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"multipart/form-data, boundary=--------------BOUNDARY------------------" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Disclaimer:
I wrote this inline here and never tested it for typos
This is a very basic way to do it and when it gets more complex, I'd look into using a Framework ...e.g. AFNetwork